# execCommand on Range

Tags: javascript, webkit, execcommand

I've been calling `execCommand` on the document to make the selected text bold or to set its color. But recently I need to use `execCommand` on a certain range and not the selected text.

Can I do this and if so how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, but it needs to be the selection. So in other words, do the following:

- Store the current selection
- Make a new selection based on the `Range`
- Perform the `execCommand`
- Restore the previous selection

You can create a `selection` from ranges (non-IE browsers) with the following:

```
 var selection = window.getSelection();
 selection.removeAllRanges();
 selection.addRange(range);
```

With IE, you can directly execute `execCommand` on `TextRange` objects, so this whole process won't be necessary.

Comment: That sounds good. One question (as I'm a beginner at javascript), how would you make a new selection? Thanks.

Comment: One thing, when I create the range and set the start offset, the number I give doesn't seem to determine the position in the text but rather the position in between nodes. Is there anyway to stop it fom doing this?

Comment: @Joshua have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html under "Programmatically creating a Range", it describes quite well there the process of creating ranges that overlap multiple nodes.

Comment: That's helpful but what if you wanted to move the cursor to the fifth letter in a div but all the text before was surrounded by bold tags. How could I convert this number to take into account for the nodes before it? Thanks very much, as I am a beginner any and all help is appreciated. :)

Comment: @Joshua You'd need to loop through the `div`s child elements, count the length of them and then using that information, select which element to start with and which to end with as well as the specific offsets for those child elements.

Comment: Got that sorted but am struggling to store the selection. I use two variables both which are created from 'window.getSelection()' and only change one, but they both end up having the same value. I'm guessing they are both pointers, so how can I actually copy the selection?